# How can I post past action with the Open Graph API and hide the little clock icon?

Tags: android-activity, facebook-opengraph, clock, facebook-timeline

I just followed [these instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/posting-past-actions/) to make a little app that can post an activity to the facebook timeline in the past, but the little icon of the clock keeps showing up in the post and because of that the two dates are shown [Little annoying clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF19l.png)

My doubt is, why the goodreads app used in the example hides the little clock icon and my app doesn't? I mean, there are certain requirements for my app to hide the icon, or should I add another parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you do not control how Facebook interprets your open graph action and displays it on Facebook. It is there for good.

Comment: Yes, i know that this feature could be used with malicious intentions, but i would like to know how can goodreads is able to post actions in the past without showing the real posting date